# Why is there 120VAC 60Hz when probing a barrel jack on the DC side with the ground reference being the outlet?

Tags: dc, ac-dc

I noticed that there is an AC signal on the DC side of the barrel jack. on the casing and the internal male probe. When I touch my oscilloscope probe to the + or - of the barrel jack with the ground of the probe disconnect on the probe, so in this case I believe it would be internally grounded through the outlet. Once the barrel jack is completely connected and secure there is a clean DC voltage.
[image]

Comment: I'll turn the question around and ask you: Why do you think there wouldn't be?

Comment: _"I believe it would be internally grounded through the outlet"_ - What evidence do you have for that belief?

Comment: Is the scope grounded? Is the power supply input grounded? Is the power supply output grounded inside the supply? What kind of power supply it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your power supply has a "floating" output (not grounded) then the inevitable capacitance that exists between the mains AC and the output will cause some leakage of the AC into the common mode DC output. Note, the differential mode output is unchanged by this common mode effect. The common mode output is referenced to the mains *ground*.

The capacitance is generally either deliberately added, as with Y capacitor(s), which are added to reduce high frequency switching noise, or is parasitic capacitance between the primary and secondary windings of a transformer / inductor.

Quite often, this common mode AC signal at the mains frequency is a "ghost" voltage. You see it with a high impedance device such as an oscilloscope, but will "disappear" or at least be greatly attenuated by grounding one side of the floating power supply output (usually the negative side). However, occasionally, the common mode AC signal is a "touch" voltage, that is, it is capable of supplying sufficient current to give someone who touches one of the DC output wires a "tingling" sensation or a mild shock. (If the shock is severe, there is something the output leads of the power supply should not be accessible to human touch!!!). DC power supplies with touch common mode voltages are, in my experience, less common. However, they are common enough that questions show up on this stack exchange site by people asking questions like "why do I get a tingling sensation when I touch metal parts of my laptop", etc.